# Sync Emacs with Okular

Tags: forward-search

To sync (I mean to have forward and reverse search working) Emacs with Okular (https://okular.kde.org/) I usually use this command:

```bash
okular -geometry 983x1388+47--10 --unique file.pdf & emacs file.tex --eval '(server-start)'
```

Is there a way to sync `Emacs` if it's already open? I mean if I open a `.tex` file just with:

```bash
emacs file.tex
```

then compile my `.tex` file (e.g. with the `tex-file` function) and, only at this point open `Okular` and get it to be in sync with `Emacs`.

Comment: You're right. Done.

Comment: Are you using `synctex`? Or some other mechanism? `okular` can supposedly use `synctex` for backwards syncing. I presume that emacs can do so as well for forward syncing, but I don't know for sure. Describing your setup in more detail might help.

Comment: Yes, I use synctex. For what I know it's the only way to have the forward and reverse search enabled.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29813/setup-synctex-with-emacs) help?

Comment: @NickD I'll need to study it carefully.